# Do large namespaces affect performance / are many small namespaces more efficient than large namespaces in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Having a single namespace for C# types like classes, structs, interfaces, enums, delegates etc. is more elegant than having many smaller namespaces but **is it less efficient**?

Does .NET Core make "references" to each type in the namespace in a way that affects performance?

Does .NET Core still create "references" in every place where I use the `using` directive for unused namespaces at the top of my class for example (in a way that affects performance)?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be efficient? Namespaces won't affect your runtime performance, nor how many classes you have in your namespace

Comment: Might be helpful if you could provide some sample-code that shows what you want to achieve here. Anyway what do you mean by "efficient"? What do you mean by "elements"?

Comment: elements are classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces are only used at *compilation time* to resolve class names & it doesn't make any difference if you have 1 huge namespace or 100 smaller ones. They allow you to simplify your code so that you do not need to write the fully qualified name of a class or method every time.

They are used to control the scope of class and method names in large projects, into more manageable chunks as the lack of "modularised" namespaces makes it arguably *harder* for engineers to read the code at a first glance.

**There is no impact on runtime performance.**